# ¿Cómo puedo obtener TODOS los registros de una tabla en SQL Server utilizando PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenas tardes:

He estado intentando obtener todos los registros de una tabla en sql server desde PHP, pero resulta que en todas las ocasiones que he probado (diferentes maneras) sólo me trae el primer registro. Cabe destacar que utilizo el modelo MVC. Pongo acá las secciones de código que interesan:

**Modelo:**

```
public function obtenerRegistros() {
    $sql = "{call obtenerTodosRegistros}";

    $params = array();

    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $this->conn, $sql , $params, $options );

    $cantidad = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt);

    if ($cantidad === false)
        return "Error";
    else
        return $cantidad;
}
```

**Vista**

```
 <?php
            if (isset($cantidad)) {
                $nuevo_arreglo = array(); 
                $arreglo = get_object_vars($cantidad);

                foreach( $cantidad as $indice=>$valor ){
                    $nuevo_arreglo[] = $valor;
                }
        ?>

            <tr>
                 <td style="width: 10%; color: #ff6633;"><?php echo $nuevo_arreglo[0];?></td>
                 <td style="width: 10%; color: #ff6633;"><?php echo $nuevo_arreglo[1];?></td>
                 <td style="width: 10%; color: #ff6633;"><?php echo $nuevo_arreglo[2];?></td>
                 <td style="width: 10%; color: #ff6633;"><?php echo $nuevo_arreglo[3];?></td>
             </tr> 

        <?php
```

**Controlador**

```
}else if($_GET['index']=="buscarTodosRegistros"){

            $cantidad=  $this->model->obtenerRegistros();

            include 'view/registrarUsuarioView.php';
            exit();
        }
```

Muchas gracias y ojalá pueda ayudarme!

Comment: MVC, excelente modelo... pero... ¿dónde está la instrucción SELECT que envías a la BD para que te devuelva todos los registros?, sería interesante conocerla. Luego, en la vista, yo crearía una variable que me concatene los diversos valores y los imprimiría al final.

Comment: En el Modelo, donde dice $sql = "{call obtenerTodosRegistros}"; estoy llamando el procedimiento almacenado obtenerTodosRegistros} el cuál posee un select * de la tabla. Yo también intenté lo de la variable, pero caigo a lo mismo, solo me trae el primer registro. Gracias por contestar!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la consulta devuelve todos los registros y los mismos son almacenados en `$cantidad`, yo haría un:
`print_r $cantidad;` para verificar que realmente hay más de un registro.

Luego, puedes construir tu tabla dentro del bucle for, si necesidad de código repetitivo. <s>Todo aquello tachado no es necesario</s>.

```
<?php
 if (isset($cantidad)) {
      $tabla='<table>';
```

<s>$nuevo_arreglo = array();</s>

<s>$arreglo = get_object_vars($cantidad);</s>

```
      foreach( $cantidad as $indice=>$valor ){
```

<s>$nuevo_arreglo[] = $valor;</s>

```
            $tabla .='<tr><td style="width: 10%; color: #ff6633;">'.$valor.'</td></tr>';
                }
       $tabla .='</table>';
       echo $tabla;

}
    ?>
```

Comment: Puse Exactamente lo que me dijiste y otra vez solo me trajo un registro, así que puse el print_r($cantidad) y el resultado fue:  stdClass Object ( [numRegistro] => 1 [Nombre] => Luis [Edad] => 21 [cedula] => 93-008-0090 ). Solo me está llegando el primero, porque si voy a la BD, el procedimiento almacenado sí me muestra todos los registros

Comment: Debe haber algún problema en la función `obtenerRegistros();` entonces, si el procedimiento funciona bien como dices. Aunque en verdad no entiendo por qué usas un procedimiento almacenado para un simple `SELECT...`.

Comment: Nos obligan en la U; no utilizar ninguna consulta en la aplicación, únicamente procedimientos. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bueno no hay problema, sólo que las procedures suelen usarse para cosas más complicadas, pero bueno... el hecho es que cuando haces esto: `$cantidad=  $this->model->obtenerRegistros();`  la función `obtenerRegistros()` está devolviendo un sólo registro por algún motivo, por tanto, debes revisar lo que hace dicha función. Por si acaso, no trates de reinventar la rueda al obtener los resultados, si necesitas un array en los resultados no lo construyas tú mismo, el manejador de la BD tiene métodos para eso.

Comment: Eso mismo estoy haciendo en este momento, revisando esa función, en especial los métodos para manejar sql desde php. Y en cuanto a lo de la BD, no lo sabía; ya mismo me pongo a investigar sobre eso. Gracias!